# Multiply and add 2 input boxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I would like the script to multiply values from input boxes by the values of hidden inputs, and print the result upon clicking the button.

Script pretty much does it but only for 1 input.

Any easy way to do it?

Much appreciated.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/3/

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <input name="inputone" id="inputone" class="calc" value="1"><span id="Total"></span>
                </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
    <input name="inputone" id="inputone" class="calc" value="1"><span id="Total"></span>
                </td>
                </tr>
    </table>
        <input name="inputtwo" id="inputtwo" class="calc" value="2" type="hidden" readonly>
        <input name="inputtwo" id="inputtwo" class="calc" value="3" type="hidden" readonly>
        <input type="button" id="update" value="Calculate" />
```

And jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#update').click(function() { 
        var inputone = $('#inputone').val();
        var inputtwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
        var totalTotal = ((inputone * 1) * (inputtwo * 1));     
        $('#Total').text(totalTotal);
    });
});
```

Comment: ids must be unique on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element IDs are not unique. You have duplicates, such as "inputone" and "inputtwo".

I've changed their names, and added a new total span.

Here's the updated code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
<input name="inputone" id="inputone" class="calc" value="1"><span id="TotalOne"></span>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
<input name="inputtwo" id="inputtwo" class="calc" value="1"><span id="TotalTwo"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
    <input name="multiplierone" id="multiplierone" class="calc" value="2" type="hidden" readonly>
    <input name="multipliertwo" id="multipliertwo" class="calc" value="3" type="hidden" readonly>
    <input type="button" id="update" value="Calculate" />
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#update').click(function() { 
        var inputone = $('#inputone').val();
        var multiplierone = $('#multiplierone').val();
        var inputtwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
        var multipliertwo = $('#multipliertwo').val();
        var totalTotalOne = (inputone * multiplierone);
        var totalTotalTwo = (inputtwo * multipliertwo);
        $('#TotalOne').text(totalTotalOne);
        $('#TotalTwo').text(totalTotalTwo);
    });
});
```

and updated jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/4/

Answer (score 0):

This little algorithm will get all the `input.calc` elements and multiply their values. Think this should work for you based on your given html.

```
var total = 1;
$("input.calc").val(function(idx, val) {
    total*= val;
})
$('#Total').text(total);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

There can never be two `IDs`Don the same page that are the same, that's why the `class` was invented.

Modify your code to something like this:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
         <input name="inputone"class="inputone calc" value="1"><span id="Total"></span>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input name="inputone" class="inputone calc" value="1"><span id="Total"></span>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <input name="inputtwo" class="calc inputtwo" value="2" type="hidden" readonly>
 <input name="inputtwo" class="calc inputtwo" value="3" type="hidden" readonly>
 <input type="button" id="update" value="Calculate" />
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#update').click(function() { 
        var inputone = $('.inputone').val();
        var inputtwo = $('.inputtwo').val();
        var totalTotal = ((inputone * 1) * (inputtwo * 1));     
        $('#Total').text(totalTotal);
    });
});
```